# teradata python module, float as NaN

Tags: python-3.x, odbc, teradata

I'm trying fetch data from teradata db and I get NaN values for the floats, but if I'm using cast(val as float) in a SQL script it's work ok. How can I fix it?

Code:

```
import teradata
    udaExec = teradata.UdaExec(appName = 'sel', version = '1.0', logConsole=False)

    session = udaExec.connect(method='odbc', 
                              system = 'db, 
                              username = 'usr, 
                              password='psw', 
                              driver= 'Teradata',
                              charset='UTF8'
                             )

    pd.read_sql('select 100000.0 as float_, 100000 as number_, cast(100000.0 as float) as float_cast', session)
```

Output:

```
float_  number_ float_cast
NaN 100000.0    100000.0
```

Comment: **1.** Floats are evil.  **2.** It's probably the Java programmer in me, but I hate implicit casts and weak typing.  **3.** What's the problem with casting it?

Comment: Casting is ok, if you have few columns, but if you need get more than 10 float columns it's can be annoying.

Answer (score 3):

I struggled with the same problem for several hours. Turns out it is quite easy to fix this without altering the teradata module.

Just add the USEREGIONALSETTINGS parameter:

```
session = udaExec.connect(
        method= 'odbc'
        , driver = 'Teradata'
        , charset = 'UTF8'
        , dsn=dsn
        , USEREGIONALSETTINGS='N'
        , username=username
        , password=password
        )
```

After that you should get what you wanted:

```
    float_      number_     float_cast
0   100000.0    100000.0    100000.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Teradata returns 100000.0 as 100000,0 so it can't be casted to numeric.
So you can edit datatypes.py file and add replace comma on dot:

```
    if value is not None:
            #added row below
            value = str(value).replace(",", ".")
            if typeCode == NUMBER:
                try:                  
                    return NUMBER(value)
                except:
                    # Handle infinity and NaN for older ODBC drivers.
                    if value == "1.#INF":
                        return NUMBER('Infinity')
                    elif value == "-1.#INF":
                        return NUMBER('-Infinity')
                    else:
                        return NUMBER('NaN')
```

May be it's a bit barbaric way, but it works.

P.S. Don't forget to restart python core after editing datatypes.py file.